# What animal is this (snake/slug/worm)?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

I found this guy in my driveway this morning. I live in Northern Florida, near Jacksonville.

I initially thought that it was a baby snake (note the black on brown lengthwise stripes), but it moves very slowly and methodically, like a slug, perhaps. Never saw a slug so long and skinny.
He's about 3.5 inches (90mm) long, and can hold his head up high to look around, raising up almost a third of his total body length.

Maybe some kind of worm?

The "hammerhead" style head is what is making me scratch mine.

[image]

Comment: Look up (Google Images) "hammerhead worm". You'll see your pretty little guy.

Comment: They are also likely to be invasive to North America, so feel free to squash if you prefer. .

Comment: Or catch it and see if it will eat an earthworm.